# pip install -e using old / stale version of setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm working on a project and recently had to update setup.py to add an extras_require field.

Prev version of project's setup.py was 1.1.3-incomplete. I bumped it up to 1.1.4-incomplete.

When I try to update the package with `pip install -e` inside my virtualenv, I get weird behavior. It's like pip is somehow caching an old copy of my setup.py file, but only in edit mode.

Here's the relevant bits of my setup.py file:

```
setup(
    name='phpIPAM-Scraper',
    version='1.1.4-incomplete',
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'configparser ; python_version < "3.2"',
        'requests',
        'beautifulsoup4',
        'tabulate',
        'click',
        'click-shell'],
    extras_require={
        'test': [
            'pytest',
            'pytest-docker',
            'pytest-docker-pexpect',
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

And old setup.py was the same, except it didn't have `extras_require` content.

When I run `pip install -e .[test]` from my project dir, I get this strange output:

```
$ pip install -e .[test]
Obtaining file:[project-dir]
  phpipam-scraper 1.1.3-incomplete does not provide the extra 'test'
Requirement already satisfied: requests ...
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 ...
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate ...
Requirement already satisfied: click ...
Requirement already satisfied: click-shell ...
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 ...
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 ...
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 ...
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 ...
Installing collected packages: phpIPAM-Scraper
  Found existing installation: phpipam-scraper 1.1.3-incomplete
    Not uninstalling phpipam-scraper at [project-dir], outside environment [virtualenv]
  Running setup.py develop for phpIPAM-Scraper
Successfully installed phpIPAM-Scraper
```

BUT, when i run the same command WITHOUT the -e flag, it installs just fine:

```
$ pip install .[test]
Processing [project-dir]
Requirement already satisfied: requests ...
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 ...
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate ...
Requirement already satisfied: click ...
Requirement already satisfied: click-shell ...
Requirement already satisfied: pytest ...
Requirement already satisfied: pytest-docker ...
Requirement already satisfied: pytest-docker-pexpect ...
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 ...
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 ...
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 ...
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 ...
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools ...
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.33 ...
Requirement already satisfied: attrs<17,>=16 ...
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect ...
Requirement already satisfied: six ...
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 ...
Building wheels for collected packages: phpIPAM-Scraper
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for phpIPAM-Scraper ... done
  Stored in directory: [local .cache]
Successfully built phpIPAM-Scraper
Installing collected packages: phpIPAM-Scraper
  Found existing installation: phpipam-scraper 1.1.3-incomplete
    Not uninstalling phpipam-scraper at [project-dir], outside environment [virtualenv-dir]
Successfully installed phpIPAM-Scraper-1.1.4-incomplete
```

This doesn't make any sense. It's like pip's edit mode is using a cached file somewhere, but i can't figure out where or how, and my googlefu has failed to find any useful information.

Have any of you fine folks ever encountered this before?

EDIT: I've deleted and recreated the virtualenv, same result. I've also set the version to 1.1.4, no change in behaviour

Comment: Have you tried deleting the virtualenv and all the `*.egg-info` etc. cruft in your repository and reinstalling?

Comment: Also, FYI, `1.1.4-incomplete` is not [a valid Python package version](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).  I recommend changing it to something like `1.1.4.dev1` for maximum interoperability with packaging tools.

Comment: I had already tried recreating the virtualenv, to no effect.

Comment: I just now tried setting the version to 1.1.4, also did not help. I've edited my initial question to add these details.

Thanks!